# flowplayer 7.0.4 /Flv file plays from local tomcat server but not from server

Tags: jsp, flash, servlets, flowplayer, swfobject

I have an application tomcat/jsp, I am trying to show video (flv -unfortunately).. the Videos are hosted on CDN. I am using tomcat 8.5,java 8.x, flowplayer 7.0.4.

Issue:
when I run tomcat on localhost:8080 and point to CDN and load the page on chrome (version 58.0.3029.81 (64-bit)) , it works plays fine.

but when I deploy the war on the server and then access the page, ( pointing to same cdn locaiton -- I print the path in jsp), it has html5 video format not spported.

I diff the "source" of both jsp/htmls form server and localhost.. they match.

if it was unsupported file-format that why it playing in local?
if it is not a file-format issue, what may be the other issue? and how can I rectify it?

Anyone has any thoughts or suggestion what might be the reason?

```
 <div id="vid1" name="vid1" class="flowplayer">
    <video>
       <source type="video/flash" src=<%=my_vid_cdn%> >
    </video>
</div>
```

[image: sever_not_working]

[image: localhost_working]

Comment: Most probably it is a crossdomain issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211846/is-flash-cross-domain-useless

Comment: @Organis, Thank you. I am reviewing the crossdomain.xml, but when I am running from the localhost, I point my cdn to load the flv, and use exact same cdn when I try to load the flv from my server..

Comment: I don't know how security sandbox behave with **localhost** urls. I advise you to install Debug Flash Player (https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html) for your browser and see if it will produce security violation alert.